# PropertyChanged is triggered, but the view is not updated

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm changing the label in the class constructor and it works fine, the label is updated ("0"). I'm also trying to update the label when I click in a button, but it's not working ("X"). I noticed debugging that the label value is updated, PropertyChanged is triggered, but the view doesn't change.

```
public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    string playerA;
    public string PlayerA
    {
        get
        {
            return playerA;
        }
        set
        {
            playerA = value;
            this.Notify("playerA");
        }
    }

    public ICommand PlayerA_Plus_Command
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        this.PlayerA_Plus_Command = new Command(this.PlayerA_Plus);
        this.PlayerA = "0";
    }

    public void PlayerA_Plus()
    {
        this.PlayerA = "X";
    }
}



public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Write your xaml here. I mean button and label + change [string platerA;] to [string playerA = "!";] if your label doesn't show ! at all, your binding has a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the parameter passed in your `PropertyChangedEventArgs` is wrong. You are using "playerA" but the name of the (**public**) property is "PlayerA" (uppercase "P"). Change `this.Notify("playerA");` to `this.Notify("PlayerA");` or even better:

`Notify(nameof(PlayerA));`

You can completely get rid of passing the name of the param by adding a `[CallerMemberName]` [attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to the `Notify()` method.

`protected void Notify([CallerMemberName] string propertyName  = null)`

This allows you to just call `Notify()` without parameters and the name of the changed property will automatically be used.

Comment: Nice to mention `[CallerMemberName]` !